# I don't understand new homebrew update output

Tags: homebrew

```
brew update

Stashing your changes:
M CODEOFCONDUCT.md
M CONTRIBUTING.md
M LICENSE.txt
M README.md
M SUPPORTERS.md

Restored your changes:
M CODEOFCONDUCT.md
M CONTRIBUTING.md
M LICENSE.txt
M README.md
M SUPPORTERS.md
Already up-to-date.
```

This was done after upgrading to the El Captain OS. Then, when I did a brew update I was asked to 'sudo chown -R$(donfox1):admin /usr/local' then this new mysterious output started happening.

I don't understand  what  changes are being 'stashed' or if I should do anything about these changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn’t do these changes you can fix them by running the following:

```
cd $(brew --repo) && git fetch && git reset --hard origin/master
```